# Sum characters from a string using a lookup table in R

Tags: r

I have a lookup dataframe (df1) like this:

```
col1 col2
A 71
R 156
N 114
D 115
...
```

and I have a data frame (df2) containing a column of strings like this:

```
[1] "AARA"                       
[2] "DDNRRRNRAAN"                      
[3] "RNDARANDRN"
...
```

I would like to create a new column in df2 that, for each string, looks up the series of corresponding numbers from df1 and sums them. So, the first row in the new column of df2 would have the value 369 (= 71 + 71 + 156 + 71). How could I go about this task?

Answer (score 2):

One more `tidyverse` strategy

```r
lookup <- structure(list(col1 = c("A", "R", "N", "D"), col2 = c(71L, 156L, 
                                                             114L, 115L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df <- structure(list(col = c("AARA", "DDNRRRNRAAN", "RNDARANDRN")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(SUM = map_dbl(str_split(col, ''), ~ sum(lookup$col2[match(.x, lookup$col1)])))

#>           col  SUM
#> 1        AARA  369
#> 2 DDNRRRNRAAN 1338
#> 3  RNDARANDRN 1182
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Split the string at every character, use `match` to get corresponding value for each character and sum them.

```
df2$res <- sapply(strsplit(df2$col, ''), function(x) 
                  sum(df1$col2[match(x, df1$col1)], na.rm = TRUE))
df2

#          col  res
#1        AARA  369
#2 DDNRRRNRAAN 1338
#3  RNDARANDRN 1182
```

---

Using the same logic a `tidyverse` option would be -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(col, sep = '') %>%
  left_join(df1, by = c('col' = 'col1')) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise(col = paste0(col, collapse = ''), 
            col2 = sum(col2, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  select(-row)
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("A", "R", "N", "D"), col2 = c(71L, 156L, 
114L, 115L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(col = c("AARA", "DDNRRRNRAAN", "RNDARANDRN")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```